# Convert asp.net password and salt password to text

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

I am using asp.net membership and I have checked the table aspnet_membership and I can see two fields password and saltpassword which look like this `QoasdDKkh5x9RizpadsGsC9N30=` and
`tO9xYGRkjaFGaskKnTVobiJnMDQ==` respectvely.

is there any tool, Stored procedure, program, online utility tool by which I can see the actual text of that password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible way you can recover the password is via brute forcing the hash against a dictionary.  This will essentially test (as many as possible) combinations of words / letters until a match is found.

Short of finding a vulnerability in the hash this is all there is.  **It was originally hashed exactly to prevent finding out the plaintext**.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of hashing a password is that you **can't** recover it (or at least not easily).

The idea is that you store a hash so you can test that against the hash calculated for the password provided by the user subsequently.